# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.xml" in logback-spring.xml level configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, xmlreader, spring-logback, jpos

I have added logback-spring.xml into the class path and it was working fine until I added below dependencies for some ISO message conversion.(crimson dependency is hardcoded in the JPOS library, so it cannot be removed)

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>iso-test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>iso-test</name>
<description>test</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>crimson</groupId>
        <artifactId>crimson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Then there is an issue with logback-spring.xml reading with below exceptions.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.xml'

and

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: Feature: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities

Below is where the JPOS packager(GenericValidatingPackager.class) used crimson library.

```
public void readFile(String filename) throws ISOException {
    XMLReader reader=XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(System.getProperty("sax.parser", "org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl"));
...
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a minimal pom to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @samabcde I have added minimum pom to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

> crimson dependency is hardcoded in the JPOS library, so it cannot be removed

This is not correct, referring to JPOS packager(GenericValidatingPackager.class)

```java
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(System.getProperty("sax.parser", "org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl"));
```

This line just tell us that if we do not set the property "sax.parser", we use
`org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl` as fallback.

So what we need:

1. Remove `crimson` dependency
2. set the property "sax.parser", e.g.

```java
System.setProperty("sax.parser", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser");
```

Comment: Once the system property is set it worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Crimson is not required by jPOS if you use a modern JVM (1.8 and up).

It was used in the past, as a fallback if the JVM didn't provide an XMLReader, and `org.xml.sax.driver` was not configured.

Also, I suggest to use the latest version [(see ChangeLog)](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/wiki/ChangeLog) as there has been a lot of improvements since 2.1.0 back in 2017.

Comment: java version 11 is used , I have changed JPOS version to 2.1.7 but the issue is there still.I have updated the post to show that JPOS is using crimson.

Comment: Oh, I get it. You're using the GenericValidatingPackager. This was a very old contribution that never get into mainstream use. Please the `GenericPackager` instead.